# python tagUI : trying to connect to https://raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpa

I am new to TagUI. I am trying out the given script on the github link for python https://github.com/tebelorg/TagUI-Python. While running the script for WEB AUTOMATION, it is trying to make connection with  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tebelorg/Tump/master/TagUI-Python/tagui.cmd
and its failing to download.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I don't track Stack Overflow for user queries. For issues and questions, raise directly to the GitHub page - https://github.com/tebelorg/RPA-Python/issues

For this error, it is probably due to your company firewall policy blocking access to GitHub. The tool requires access to GitHub where it hosts dependencies to be downloaded.

If your company network is blocked, you can use the `pack()` and `update()` functions to deploy this package without the internet - https://github.com/tebelorg/RPA-Python#core-functions

PS - also, I've recently renamed the project RPA for Python and is available with `pip install rpa`